# Using enhanced for loop to return the index of the largest number in an array

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with using the foreach loop to find the index of the largest number in an array.

I am getting: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5"

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks! Here is my code:

```
   public static int enhanIntMax(int[] a){
    int largeIndex =0;
    int largeArrnum=scores[0];
    for( int i : a){
        if(a[i] >largeArrnum){``
            largeArrnum += a[i];
            largeIndex += i;

        }
    }
    return largeIndex;
        }

  public static void main(string[] args){
  int[] a={1,2,3,4,5};
 System.out.println(enhanInMax(a));
}
```

Comment: `if(a[i]`...`i` is the value, not the index.

Comment: `a[4] = 5`,  line 5 will try to access `a[i]` with `i=5`

Comment: You might want to check out some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/471/for-each#t=201608082056505284714) of how to use an enhanced for loop. It doesn't give index values. It's intended to be compatible with structures that don't have them.

Comment: Where does `scores` come from?

Comment: sorry  @PM77-1 that was supposed to be int largArrnum = a[0];

Comment: hey @4castle so what you mean is enhanced for loop can be used for returning index values......gush if so ill be glad and just stick with normal for loop ..anyways thanks a whole lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've worked it out from the comments, but the trouble here is :

```
if(a[i] > largeArrnum)
```

won't try to compare the element with the value of i against largeArrnum, but rather the ith element of a. By using an enhanced for loop, the "for(int i = 0; i < blah blah blah... " part of the loop is handled for you. Rather than iterate across the indices of the array, an enhanced loop iterates across its contents. Therefore, if at any point a value of a[i] is greater than the length, you'll get this error. The right way to fix it is to just replace "a[i]" with "i", but you might want to give this site a quick review first:
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Comment: hey @LordFarquaad thanks so much, but i just found out enhanced for loop can't be used for returning index values in arrays

Answer (score 0):

The for-each loop doesn't give you a means to directly access the current index. So you'd have to track it yourself. For example, with `p` and something like

```
public static int enhanIntMax(int[] a) {
    int p = 0, largeIndex = 0, largeArrnum = a[0];
    for (int i : a) { // <-- for each int i in a
        if (i > largeArrnum) { // <-- if the value is greater then
            largeArrnum = i; // <-- update the value
            largeIndex = p; // <-- update the largest index
        }
        p++; // <-- update the position p.
    }
    return largeIndex; // <-- return the largest index.
}
```

**Note** That this is **both** easier to read and also slightly more efficient (because it skips comparing element `0` with itself) with a regular `for` loop like

```
public static int enhanIntMax(int[] a) {
    int largeIndex = 0, largeArrnum = a[0];
    for (int p = 1; p < a.length; p++) {
        if (a[p] > largeArrnum) {
            largeArrnum = a[p];
            largeIndex = p;
        }
    }
    return largeIndex;
}
```

Comment: wow!! brilliant @Elliott Frisch   .....gush thank you so much i've been on this for long i almost gave up , thanks so much again

Comment: wish i had someone like you around to be explaining some faustrating topics and questions in java

Answer (score -1):

With Java 8 you can now use:

```
int maxint = Arrays.stream(A)
               .max()
               .getAsInt();
  int index = Arrays.asList(A).indexOf(maxInt);
```